# How to hide email with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, email, bots, hide, mailto

```js
let user = 'larr';
let domain = 'outlook.com';
let send = 'ilt';

document.getElementById("bots").href = "ma" + send + "o:" + user + "@" + domain;
```

```html
<a id="bots"> <img src="imgs/pic.jpg"> </a>
```

Here is my code I have so far. Hiding the email address from bots is required for the project, and I'd like to use "mailto:" as well.
I have exhausted all online resources and everything I've tried does not work(JS novice). I have looked at every single documentation I could find on this, tried every piece of code that made sense and have asked my professor for help (they use jquery not js). Please help. I just do not understand JS enough yet to see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: In what way does your attempt "not work"?  The code shown does not itself contain the email address, but does successfully include the email address in a `mailto:` link.  What's the problem?

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your reply. When I click the email icon that's nested in the "a" tag, nothing happens. My goal is for the email client to pop of for the user. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe try something like this: http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/anti-spam.html

Comment: Thank you Seb. My professor wants it done in JS, but this works great, and perhaps they will accept this method. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I run the code in the question and click the link, my email client opens with larr@outlook.com

Comment: Oh thank you for that. perhaps another piece of my code is interfering with it from working properly.  That is a good clue to hunt down the problem. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine. Perhaps clear your browser's cache?

```
 let user = 'larr';
 let domain = 'outlook.';
 let com = 'com';
 let send = 'ilt';

 let bots = document.getElementById("bots");
 bots.href = "ma"+send+"o:"+user+"@"+domain+com;
```